# Google Drive API v2 q=sharedWithMe returns files from "My Drive" folder

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I use java google drive api v2(1.22.0), and when I try to get list files from **"Shared With Me"** folder using *drive.files.list* and query *"sharedWithMe and trashed = false"* it returns files from **"My Drive"**. I was try same code on several accounts, all works fine except one user with empty "Shared With Me"(it does't meter other account also has empty this folder but works fine). I got same affect by using example on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: After more testing I found case that reproduce this problem. So if I have two accounts "A" and "B" and do steps: 'A'->create file; 'A'->share file with 'B'; A->change owner for this file to 'B'. Then my problem is reproduce. So can anyone help me to filter sharedWithMe files according google drive view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my case help query **"sharedWithMe and trashed = false and not 'me' in owners"**. So Google remember that file was shared ant this option is independent. And also looks like this query is a same like in google view for "Shared With Me" folder.
P.S. If any found some other case for my question, please attach a link))